# CardView with RelativeLayout not updating properly after click

Tags: android-studio, cardview

I am trying to change one of my textview(Status) when clicked but it just removes the current text and displays my original text's text.
The textview currently display either "Not Taken" or "Pending" depending on what data is retrieved from my db.

My pop up dialog fragment code that shows the card items in a recyclerview.

```
   public class FragmentLocationPopup extends DialogFragment {

        View mView;
        TextView tvSelectedBranch;
        RecyclerView mScheduleList;
        ScheduleAdapter mAdapter;
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

        String TAG = "DialogFragment";

        ArrayList<Schedule> scheduleList;
        VariablesHolder variablesHolder;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_popup, container, false);

        createScheduleList();
        buildRecyclerView();

        return mView;
    }

    public void createScheduleList(){

        scheduleList = new ArrayList<>();
        tvSelectedBranch = mView.findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedBranch);

        variablesHolder = (VariablesHolder) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        String selectedBranch = variablesHolder.getSelectedBranch();

        tvSelectedBranch.setText(selectedBranch);
        Log.d(TAG, "Selected branch = "+selectedBranch);

        Call<List<Schedule>> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApiDate().getSchedule();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Schedule>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Schedule>> call, Response<List<Schedule>> response) {

                List<Schedule> schedules = response.body();

                for (Schedule schedule : schedules) {
                    if(schedule.getBranchID().equals(variablesHolder.getBranchID())) {
                        scheduleList.add(new Schedule(schedule.getWorkScheduleFromDateTime(), schedule.getWorkScheduleToDateTime(),schedule.getWorkScheduleStatus()));
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + schedule.getWorkScheduleFromDateTime() + " and " + schedule.getWorkScheduleToDateTime() + " and "+schedule.getWorkScheduleStatus());
                    }
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Schedule>> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });

        String asd = ""+variablesHolder.getBranchIdList();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: "+asd);
    }

    public void buildRecyclerView(){
        mScheduleList = mView.findViewById(R.id.rvScheduleList);
        mScheduleList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mView.getContext());
        mAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(scheduleList);

        mScheduleList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mScheduleList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ScheduleAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                changeItem(position, "Clicked");

            }
        });
    }

    public void changeItem(int position, String text){
        scheduleList.get(position).changeText1(text);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        Log.d(TAG, "changeItem: "+position+" / "+text);
    }
}
```

My schedule class (I only use 3 variables in it at the moment) workfromtime, worktotime, and workstatus

```
   public class Schedule {

    private String workScheduleID;
    private Date  workScheduleFromDateTime;
    private Date workScheduleToDateTime;
    private String workScheduleStatus;
    private String workDescriptionID;
    private String branchID;
    private String staffID;
    private String managerID;
    private String workScheduleBidDateTime;

    public Schedule(Date workScheduleFromDateTime, Date workScheduleToDateTime,String workScheduleStatus) {
        this.workScheduleFromDateTime = workScheduleFromDateTime;
        this.workScheduleToDateTime = workScheduleToDateTime;
        this.workScheduleStatus = workScheduleStatus;
    }

    public void changeText1(String workScheduleStatus){
        this.workScheduleStatus = workScheduleStatus;
    }

    public String getWorkScheduleID(){return workScheduleID;}
    public Date getWorkScheduleFromDateTime(){return workScheduleFromDateTime;}
    public Date getWorkScheduleToDateTime(){return workScheduleToDateTime;}
    public String getWorkScheduleStatus(){return workScheduleStatus;}
    public String getWorkDescriptionID(){return workDescriptionID;}
    public String getBranchID(){return branchID;}
    public String getStaffID(){return staffID;}
    public String getManagerID(){return managerID;}
    public String getWorkScheduleBidDateTime(){return workScheduleBidDateTime;}

}
```

Adapter class

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScheduleAdapter.ScheduleViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "ScheduleAdapter";
    private ArrayList<Schedule> mScheduleList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;


    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class ScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        public TextView FromTime,ToTime,ScheduleStatus,Tester;

        public ScheduleViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);

            FromTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFromTime);
            ToTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvToTime);
            ScheduleStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
            Tester = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ScheduleAdapter(ArrayList<Schedule> scheduleList ){
        mScheduleList = scheduleList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.schedule_item,parent,false);
        ScheduleViewHolder svh = new ScheduleViewHolder(mView, mListener);
        return svh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Schedule currentSchedule = mScheduleList.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+currentSchedule.getWorkScheduleFromDateTime() + " and "+currentSchedule.getWorkScheduleToDateTime());

        String FromTimeRegion = currentSchedule.getWorkScheduleFromDateTime().toString().replace("GMT 2020","");
        String ToTimeRegion = currentSchedule.getWorkScheduleToDateTime().toString().replace("GMT 2020","");
        String status = currentSchedule.getWorkScheduleStatus();

        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+status);

        if(status.toLowerCase().equals("pending")) {
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setText("Pending");
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
        }
        if(status.toLowerCase().equals("not taken")) {
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setText("Not Taken");
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7FFF00"));
        }

        holder.FromTime.setText("From: "+FromTimeRegion);
        holder.ToTime.setText("To: "+ToTimeRegion);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mScheduleList.size();
    }
}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it is caused by this part of my code.

```
 if(status.toLowerCase().equals("pending")) {
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setText("Pending");
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"));
        }
        if(status.toLowerCase().equals("not taken")) {
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setText("Not Taken");
            holder.ScheduleStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7FFF00"));
        }

        holder.FromTime.setText("From: "+FromTimeRegion);
        holder.ToTime.setText("To: "+ToTimeRegion);
```

Just had to edit which comes first.